# Add a module to an existing distribution with ExtUtils::ModuleMaker

Tags: perl, module, helper, software-distribution

I work on a Perl distribution using a [ExtUtils::ModuleMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::ModuleMaker) basis. I am in the need of creating other modules (`.pm` files) in this distribution. I would like to generate them using the same `modulemaker` template.

I know that it is possible to achieve with [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter) and [Module::Starter::Smart](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter::Smart) plugin by adding a `--distro` parameter:

```
# create a new distribution named 'Foo-Bar'
$ module-starter --module=Foo::Bar

# ... then add a new module
$ module-starter --module=Foo::Bar::Me --distro=Foo-Bar
```

Is there such a thing for `modulemaker`?

Comment: Don't see anything in the docs, but you should be able to copy the existing `.pm` and do a search-and-replace for the package name therein. You'll also need to add the file to the `MANIFEST` file.